# Подключение библиотеки jquery и других скриптов

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть страница с кнопкой.
И подключенные яваскрипты

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cart.js"></script>
```

Помимо этой кнопки на странице куча всего.
Нажатие на эту кнопку запускает `cart.js`.
В фаерфоксе и хроме все работает идеально, однако в опере кнопка отрабатывает 1 раз из 5 обновлений страницы.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо видеть кнопку и ее обработчик в cart.js

Comment: @votanko, открывайте консоль браузера, чтобы видеть ошибки js и перезагружайте страницу.

Comment: в консоль ошибки не выводятся